# regexp python with parsing html page

Tags: python, regex

Good day.
Little problem with regexp.

I have a regexp that look like

```
rexp2 = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', data)
```

And i need to grab all in

```
<div id="header">
<h1></h1>
<p>
localhost OpenWrt Backfire<br />
Load: 0.00 0.00 0.00<br />
Hostname: localhost
</p>
</div>
```

But my code doesnt work :(
What im doing wrong?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4):

**Statutory Warning**: It is a [Bad Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) to parse (X)HTML using regular expression.

Fortunately there is a **better way.** To get going, first install the [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module. Next, read up on the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html). Third, code!

Here is one way to do what you are trying to do:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = """<div id="header">
<h1></h1>
<p>
localhost OpenWrt Backfire<br />
Load: 0.00 0.00 0.00<br />
Hostname: localhost
</p>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for each in soup.findAll(name = 'p'):
    print each
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions this way.  Try parsing HTML with Beautiful Soup instead and walk the DOM tree.

Comment: Ok.How can a do it with beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0):

dot is not mathching enter, use re.DOTALL

```
re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', data, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `re.M` (multiline) flag to match multiline strings. But parsing HTML with regexps isn't a particularly good idea.

It looks like you want some stats from an OpenWrt-powered router. Why don't you write simple CGI script that outputs required information in *machine-readable* format?