# My webcrawler isn't looping to get all the links - using foo function (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

I am creating a webcrawler and in the first step, I need to crawl a website and extract all its link however my code is not looping to extract. I tried using append but that results in a list of lists. I'm trying to use foo and I get an error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

import re

def get_all_urls(url):

    get_content = urlopen(url).read()
    url_list = []

    find_url = re.compile(r'a\s?href="(.*)">')
    url_list_temp = find_url.findall(get_content)
    for i in url_list_temp:
        url_temp = url_list_temp.pop()
        source = 'http://blablabla/'
        url = source + url_temp
        url_list.append(url)
    #print url_list
    return url_list


def web_crawler(seed):

    tocrawl = [seed]
    crawled = []

    i = 0

    while i < len(tocrawl):
        page = tocrawl.pop()
        if page not in crawled:
            #tocrawl.append(get_all_urls(page))
            foo = (get_all_urls(page))
            tocrawl = foo
            crawled.append(page)
        if not tocrawl:
            break
    print crawled
    return crawled
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a bad idea to parse HTML with regular expressions, for all reasons listed:

- here: [Python regular expression for HTML parsing (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391/python-regular-expression-for-html-parsing-beautifulsoup)
- here: [Python regex to match HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566851/python-regex-to-match-html)
- here: [regexp python with parsing html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651589/regexp-python-with-parsing-html-page)
- and so on..

You should use an HTML parser to to the job. Python provides one in its standard library:  [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html), but you could also use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) or even [lxml](http://lxml.de/). I tend to favor BeautifulSoup, for its nice API.

Now, back to your problem, you're modifying the list you're iterating on:

```
for i in url_list_temp:
    url_temp = url_list_temp.pop()
    source = 'http://blablabla/'
    ...
```

This is bad, because it metaphorically amounts to sawing a branch you're sitting on.
Also, you do not seem to require this removal, as there is no condition for which an url must be removed or not.

Finally, you get an error after using `append` because, as you said, it creates a list of list. You should use `extend` instead.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> l1.append(l2)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l1.extends(l2)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

NB: Take a look at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/ for additional help with scraping with beautifulsoup